# Embedding Video in a WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms, video

I need to be able to embed and control the playback of an AVI file in a WinForms app, using C#.  The video needs to be embedded in the form, not launched in a separate media player window.

What's the best approach to do this?  I found the System.Media namespace, which sounded promising, but it appears that is only useful for sound.

Do I use DirectX to do this?  MCI?  Or some other approach?

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Media Player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb249260(VS.85).aspx) inside your Winform. This would been an easy way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

The way i did it was, and I quote:

> Right-click the Toolbox, and click Choose Items.
>
> Note: If you do not see the Toolbox, click Toolbox on the View menu to
>   open it. The Customize Toolbox Items dialog box opens.
>
> On the COM Components tab, select the Windows Media Player check box,
>   and then click OK.
>
> The Windows Media Player control appears on the current Toolbox tab.
>
> When you add the Windows Media Player control to the Toolbox, Visual
>   Studio automatically adds references to two libraries: AxWMPLib and
>   WMPLib. The next step is to add the control to the Windows Form.
>
> To add the Windows Media Player control to a Windows Form
>
> Drag the Windows Media Player control from the Toolbox to the Windows
>   Form.
>
> In the Properties window, set the Dock property to Fill. You can do
>   this by clicking the center square.
>
> Double-click the title bar of the form to add the default Load event
>   in the Code Editor.
>
> Add the following code to the Form_Load event handler to load a video
>   when the application opens.

```
axWindowsMediaPlayer1.URL = 
    @"http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=95772";
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383953(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend this library:

http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

It is a .NET wrapper around the DirectShow API.

(The sample apps should get you going very quickly.)

--Bruce

Comment: Thanks. You may have answered this question as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464613/looking-for-a-component-net-or-com-activex-that-can-play-avi-files-in-a-winfor

Comment: Have you ever used this? It looks like the sample app can do what I need, but the sample apps for DirectShow.NET don't make much sense to me. I can run it and play a file, and it loops automatically, but all this is done internally and I can't find any way to modify it to play multiple files in succession.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestions from [Daok](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332117/embedding-video-in-a-winforms-app#332131) and [Brian Genisio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332117/embedding-video-in-a-winforms-app#332141) are both good options. Let me add a third: DirectShow. Used to be part of DirectX but has now been promoted to the Windows SDK. There are many good C# sample applications to look at, and it gives complete control of the playback.

Answer (score -1):

I would **consider** using the WPF media controls and just use the ElementHost to put your WPF control inside your WinForms app.  I think you will get a much more rich experience.

See [System.Windows.Forms.Integration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.aspx) for more information